# Seems like Rails do caching, which I don't want it to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is `@avalibable_colors=['#5A009D', '#004DFF', '#F4F400', '#FF8000']` variable (it is not instance of model), which represent avaliable options - colors, which hadn't been taken yet, through method:

```
def choose_color
  @check=Check.find(params[:check_id])
  @colorschemes=@check.colorschemes
  current_colors=[]
  @check.colorschemes.each do  |c|
    current_colors.push(c.color)
  end
  @avalibable_colors=['#5A009D', '#004DFF', '#F4F400', '#FF8000']
  current_colors.each do |c|
    if @avalibable_colors.index(c)
      @avalibable_colors[@avalibable_colors.index(c)]=nil
    end
  end
  @avalibable_colors.compact!
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

After that `@avalibable_colors` contents only untaken color options.

And generally it works. If I choose 1 color option, it displays rest 4, if 2 - rest 3, if I choose one, and then delete it - it is in avaliable colors.

And that works until whole four. And If I add all four, and then delete one by one, no colors are avaliable **until I refresh page**.

Server logs:

```
Started GET "/choose_color?check_id=46" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-13 19:00:31 +0400
Processing by ColorschemesController#choose_color as JS
  Parameters: {"check_id"=>"46"}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."auth_token" = 'oPXJtztDkYdYmVsQ3wxxfQ' LIMIT 1
  Check Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "checks".* FROM "checks" WHERE "checks"."id" = 46 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "checks".* FROM "checks" WHERE "checks"."id" = 46 LIMIT 1
  Check Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "checks".* FROM "checks" WHERE "checks"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "46"]]
  Colorscheme Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "colorschemes".* FROM "colorschemes" WHERE "colorschemes"."check_id" = 46
  Rendered colorschemes/_choose_color.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered colorschemes/choose_color.js.erb (5.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 33ms (Views: 22.0ms | ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
```

Comment: This doens't make much sense to me. What has it got to do with caching?

Comment: We'd need to see client code to diagnose this.  Looks like a javascript issue rather than any problem with the controller action.

Comment: @FrederickCheung, because rails controller method defines `@avaliable_colors`, based on DB records, then template uses it. And when I add all four options, and then delete each one of them, `@avaliable_colors` still empty (should not be, cause method is called after deleting). But if you are asking, what it have to do with caching, please say another possible reasons why **page reloading fixes it**.

Comment: That sounds more like a client side issue although I'm struggling to understand what is going on here

Comment: @FrederickCheung, possibly you are right about client side, because it works normally in Chrome, but not in Firefox. Or I don't know what does it mean. Looks like black magic ;( But now really works in Chrome as supposed to